# Rails STI query all subclasses using base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

Imagine I have this STI table called living things with these such subclasses:

```
class LivingThing < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Animal < LivingThing
end

class Plant < LivingThing
end

class Fungus < LivingThing
end

class Cat < Animal
end

class Dog < Animal
end
```

I am trying to get a very simple query of all records that INHERIT from subclass "Animal". 
So I want records wher type= "Cat" or type= "Dog".  I don't know why I can't seem to figure this out.

none of these options work:

```
- animals = LivingThing.all.map{|r| r.kind_of?("Animal")}
- animals = LivingThing.all.map{|r| r.type == "Animal"}
- animals = LivingThing.kind_of?("Animal")
```

currently LivingThing.all =

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Cat id: 2,  status: 1,  created_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20">, #<Dog id: 3,  status: 1,  created_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20">,#<Cat id: 4,  status: 1,  created_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20">, #<Cat id: 5,  status: 1,  created_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20">, #<Rose id: 6,  status: 1,  created_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20">, #<Oak id: 7,  status: 1,  created_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20">, #<Mushroom id: 6,  status: 1,  created_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20">, #<Ringworm id: 8,  status: 1,  created_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:57:20">]>
```

Comment: Why can't you just call Animal.all instead of LivingThing.all ? It's also better for performance wise.

Comment: I am passing the base class in as a param....do you know how I could do param[:base_class].all ?

Comment: when I try I get undefined method `all' for "Animal":String

Comment: You should call param[:base_class].constantize.all

Comment: I've made a question now...if you'd like to go there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213553/sti-type-from-a-dynamic-form-parameter-in-rails-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
animals = LivingThing.all.map { |r| r if r.class.superclass.name == 'Animal' }
```

or:

```
animals = LivingThing.all.map { |r| r if r.class.superclass == Animal }
```

This should give you all the records of classes that are subclassed from the **Animal** class.

Comment: That returns an array like this "[true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false]",  I'm looking for the actual records...not if each record does or doesn't inherit from that class

Comment: that gives me "[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false] "

Comment: that should clearly return the array of records. Can you post the output of `LivingThing.all`?

Comment: I had to put it in the question, as it was too long for the comments

Comment: ok. Now can you also put what you see when you do this: `LivingThing.all.map{ |r| r.inspect if r.class.superclass.name == "Animal" }`?

Comment: => ["#<Cat id: 2, type: \"Cat\", date: \"2016-09-01\", status: 1, created_at: \"2016-03-25 00:57:20\", updated_at: \"2016-03-25 00:57:20\">"...etch

Comment: OK, you do get the expected results, right? `LivingThing.all.map{ |r| r if r.class.superclass.name == "Animal" }`

Comment: yes, that works to bring up the records, but they have those "\"

Comment: Just do without the inspect

Comment: ah,  your code is working....now when I try to do animals.each do |animal| then I get a nil class error...that's a separate question.  I will mark yours as complete.

Comment: You'll want to add a `.select(&:present)` (for Ruby <2.7) or use `.filter_map()` (for Ruby 2.7+) in order to remove any nil's from this mapping.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are landing on this question and you're running and your `ParentClass.all` is not returning all of the subclass records... In Rails 6.0, the query not automatically return all subclasses.

You'll need to add the following in the parent class and specify each subclass that you would like to support:

`require_dependency 'subclass_name'`

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#autoloading-and-sti for more details

For Rails 7, a slightly different approach is recommended here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#single-table-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

As of rails 4.2 (maybe even before), doing:

`Animal.all` will automatically render an sql call something like:

`SELECT * FROM "living_things" WHERE "living_things"."type" IN ('Animal', 'Dog', 'Cat')`

So there you have it. :-)