# sti type from a dynamic form parameter in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I am looking to pass an sti base class as a param and then be able to call all the child classes from that query.
br/
This is my STI Class & Subclasses.

```
class LivingThing < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Animal < LivingThing
end

class Plant < LivingThing
end

class Fungus < LivingThing
end

class Cat < Animal
end

class Dog < Animal
end
```

I would like to pass a param through a rendered form called "living_thing_type" so I can do this:

```
<%= render 'form', living_thing_type: "Animal" %>

living_things = living_thing_type.all
```

but even when I try this

```
living_thing_type.constantize.all
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `all' for "Animal":String
```

Comment: What did you assign to `living_thing_type`? If `living_thing_type` is indeed 'Animal', it won't throw the `undefined method `all' for "Animal":String` as you are doing `constantize` on the string which will return the `class` of `Animal`.

Comment: I did constantize and it worked!  I wanted to give you the chance to answer that here as it's not very easy to find documentation for that for me.